# ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object>>": "BlogComment.user_name" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, авторизация, auth, forms, регистрация

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы и зарегистрированные и не зарегистрированные пользователи могли оставлять комментарии. Если пользователь авторизован, то все работает нормально. Но если отправлять комментарий от не авторизованного пользователя, то вылезает ошибка:

ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f5fd441bf70>>": "BlogComment.user_name" must be a "User" instance.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

views.py

```
class AddBlogComment(View):
   def post(self, request, pk):
       form = BlogCommentForm(request.POST)
       blog = Blog.objects.get(id=pk)
       if form.is_valid():
           pk = request.POST.get('id', None)
           form = form.save(commit=False)
           if pk is not None:
               form.parent = BlogUserComment.objects.get(id=pk)
           form.blog = blog
           if request.user:
               form.user_name = request.user
           else:
               print(request.POST)
           form.save()
       return redirect(blog.get_absolute_url())
```

models.py

```
class BlogUserComment(MPTTModel):
   blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="блог")

   user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Имя пользователя", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
   quest_name = models.CharField("Гость", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   comment_text = models.TextField("Комментарий", max_length=5000)
   comment_date = models.DateTimeField("Дата", auto_now_add=True)

   parent = TreeForeignKey('self', verbose_name="Родительский комментарий", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')

   comment_moderate = models.BooleanField("Модерация", default=False)

   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.id} - {self.comment_text}"

   class MPTTMeta:
       ordering_insertion_by = ['-id']

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = "Отзыв пользователя"
       verbose_name_plural = "Отзывы пользователей"
       ordering = ['-id']
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'add_comment_url' blog.id %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.non_field.errors }}
{% if user.is_active %}
   <div class="comment-text mb-2">
      <label for="commentTextArea">Ваш отзыв *</label>
      <textarea rows="7" name="comment_text" id="commentTextArea" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
   </div>
{% else %}
   <div class="comment-text mb-2">
      <label for="commentQuestName">Ваше имя *</label>
      <input type="text" name="quest_name" id="commentQuestName" class="form-control" required="">
      <label for="commentTextArea">Ваш отзыв *</label>
      <textarea rows="7" name="comment_text" id="commentTextArea" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
    </div>
{% endif %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Отправить отзыв</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated
```